# VBA Excel case-based string search in the range

Tags: excel, vba

I am going to copy the data, which will next be sorted with relation to the certain string occurring in the range (head columns).  This data is going to be various, so I decided to put everything in the cases instead of IF conditions.

My code looks as below:

```
 Sub Selection()
 Dim rng1 As Range
 Dim strSearch As String
 Set rng1 = Range("A:P").Find(strSearch)

 Select Case strSearch
 Case "Hel."
 If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
 Call SunButton
 Else
    MsgBox ("Solar ephemeris not found or corrupted")
 End If
 Case "Libration"
 If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
 Call MoonButton
 Else
    MsgBox ("Lunar ephemeris not found or corrupted")
End If
End Select
End Sub
```

And I am wondering why it isn't working.

[image]

Is there any way to base the case statement on the string search at once?

UPDATE:

After rebuilding my code, the macro cannot see the occurring string in my data provided

```
 Sub SelectionB()
 Dim rng As Range
 Dim strSearch As String, strSearch2 As String, strSearch3 As String
 Set rng = Range("A:P").Find(strSearch)

 strSearch = "Hel."
 strSearch2 = "----Libration----"
 strSearch3 = ""

 Select Case rng
 Case strSearch
 If Not rng Is Nothing Then
 Call SunButton
 Else
    MsgBox ("Solar ephemeris not found or corrupted")
 End If
 Case strSearch2
 If Not rng Is Nothing Then
 Call MoonButton
 Else
    MsgBox ("Lunar ephemeris not found or corrupted")
 End If
 Case strSearch3
 MsgBox ("Please provide the Astropixels.com")
 End Select
 End Sub
```

I am only getting the last msgbox. It shouldn't be like this as I have the data populated (see in the image).

Comment: You really should specify more parameters of `Range.Find`. Also, where do you assign `strSearch` a value?

Comment: strSearch is a string not a value. I a looking for a specific string or its part

Comment: In other words, where is the line `strSearch = ...`?

Comment: in the case 
Select Case StrSearch and case = ".Hel"

Comment: That's not what `Select Case` does. `Case ".Hel"` assumes that `strSearch` *already* has been assigned the value `".Hel"`.

Comment: ok, so I have to base the Case on my rng then

Comment: Are you looking for only one string out of a range of possible?

Comment: .Find(strSearch) will also not work because strSearch is blank, so excel will jump to the next blank cell. Therefore rng will be a blank cell.

Comment: Set rng = Range("A:P").Find(strSearch)  '<==finds first blank cell

Comment: But I definied StrSearch already

Answer (score 0):

I think you first need to restrict the search range in your find to the appropriate row and column. You need to ensure you search for a term after assignment or it will look find the first blank cell.

Additionally, I think you want a loop looking for various possible terms and according to if found do something

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Selections()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim search As Variant, search1 As String, search2 As String, search3 As String
    
    search1 = "Hel."
    search2 = "----Libration----"
    search3 = vbNullString
    
    For Each search In Array(search1, search2, search3)
        
        Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:P1").Find(search) 'Restrict range and apply after you have a value to look for then test if Is Nothing
        
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            Select Case rng.Value                'test the explicit default member
            Case search1
                SunButton
            Case search2
                MoonButton
            Case search3
                MsgBox "Please provide the Astropixels.com"
            End Select
        Else
            Select Case search
            Case search1
                MsgBox "Solar ephemeris not found or corrupted"
            Case search2
                MsgBox "Lunar ephemeris not found or corrupted"
            End Select
        End If
       
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The macro skips through all cases, which I can see by appearing the Msgboxes. Finally reaches the last one..please provide the data...

Comment: Please can you provide your data in a format we can copy. Supply it as a markdown table rather than an image. Also,  are your headers in the Activesheet and in row 1 of that sheet?

Comment: It applies to the 1st row from A1 to P1. This is the range, where I want to pick up the string from.

Comment: I tested it with using headers as you show it and it works. Bear in mind, I am not doing anything with the column. Put the msgbox in instead of SunButton etc and you should get a message. Better still use an explicit worksheet name reference rather than activesheet.